# A csv file not opening correctly

Tags: excel

I am having a problem to open a csv file.

I have a export button. On click, a csv file is generated with data from my database.

The generated file is opening correctly at my place but the same file is breaking on my client pc.

Can someone help me out with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Form csv properly as follows,

```
$arr = ("data1,data2,data3,data3","data1,data2,data3,data3","data1,data2,data3,data3");
$fp = fopen('/tmp/reports.csv', 'w');
foreach ($arrData as $line) {
 fputcsv($fp, explode(',', $line));
}
fclose($fp);
header('Content-type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="reports.csv"');
readfile('/tmp/reports.csv');
```